# mutliple application.yaml in config directory of mutliple libraries

Tags: spring-boot

I'm developing multiple tiny libraries (external jars) and I need to have them add their application.yml so that they can get discovered by 1 spring boot having them as dependencies. This worked fine for the first library, but it seems that as soon as I have more than 1, the 2nd one is ignored (spring boot overwrites the first one because of classpath collision?).

What's the proper way to do this?

Comment: Byhardcoding the defaults instead of putting them in yaml files. Only one file can be loaded from the classpath and generally that is the one shipped withthe application itself, not the library.

Comment: And if you want to change the default behavior of spring boot? Let's say that you want all  consumers of the libary to have automatically (by default) all actuator endpoints enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you rename them to be more specific like `abc.yml` and `abc-prod.yml` (for all your stages). You could then create an [`EnvironmentPostProcessor`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/env/EnvironmentPostProcessor.html) that reads your YAML files and adds all properties to the context. This is a working example for an `EnvironmentPostProcessor` that does this exact thing:

```java
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor;
import org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader;
import org.springframework.core.env.ConfigurableEnvironment;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Optional;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static java.util.function.Predicate.not;

public class MyPropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {

    private static final Set<String> KNOWN_STAGES = Set.of("local", "dev", "ref", "abn", "prod");
    private final YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();

    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment environment, SpringApplication application) {
        Stream.concat(Arrays.stream(environment.getActiveProfiles())
                                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                                .filter(KNOWN_STAGES::contains),
                        Stream.of(""))
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .distinct()
                .map(this::loadYaml)
                .forEach(environment.getPropertySources()::addLast);
    }

    private PropertySource<?> loadYaml(final String stage) {
        final String stageSuffix = Optional.ofNullable(stage).filter(not(String::isEmpty)).map("-"::concat).orElse("");
        final ClassPathResource configFile = new ClassPathResource(String.format("abc%s.yml", stageSuffix));
        if (!configFile.exists())
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Config file %s does not exist", configFile));
        try {
            return loader.load(String.format("abc%s", stageSuffix), configFile).get(0);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(String.format("Failed to load %s", configFile), e);
        }
    }

}
```

Note that the properties are added with the `addLast` method. You could also use `addFirst` depending on whether you want your properties to be able to be overwritten by the Spring Boot application using your library or whether you want to override `application.yml` values of the Spring Boot application.

Make sure to create a [`spring.factories`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration.locating-auto-configuration-candidates) file in the `src/main/resources/META-INF` directory of your library where you register your `EnvironmentPostProcessor` as well so that the Spring Boot application using your library knows that this `EnvironmentPostProcessor` needs to be called:

```
org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessor=\
com.myproject.MyPropertiesEnvironmentPostProcessor
```

This [Baeldung article](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-environmentpostprocessor) is also a good read.